# Couldn't find the image pushed in dockerhub using buildkit and argo workflow

Tags: argo-workflows, docker-buildkit, argo, buildkit

I'm trying to build and push a docker image from a dockerfile to my private repo in dockerhub using buildctl-daemonless.sh command using argo workflow, the following is the step in the workflow that does the job. The problem is that I get that it runs successfully but I couldn't find the image pushed

```
- name: image
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: path
          - name: image
      volumes:
        - name: test-secret-secret
          secret:
            secretName: test-secret-secret
      container:
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: [ sh, -c, "buildctl debug workers" ]
        image: moby/buildkit:v0.9.3-rootless
        volumeMounts:
          - name: work
            mountPath: /work
          - name: test-secret-secret
            mountPath: /.docker
        workingDir: /work/{{inputs.parameters.path}}
        env:
          - name: BUILDKITD_FLAGS
            value: --oci-worker-no-process-sandbox
          - name: DOCKER_CONFIG
            value: /.docker
        command: [ sh, -c, "buildctl-daemonless.sh" ]
        args:
          - build
          - --frontend=dockerfile.v0
          - --local context=.
          - --local dockerfile=.
          - --output type=image,name=docker.io/myusername/repo-test:argoworkflow,push=true
```

The only thing I get from the logs is this

```
time="2024-03-31T11:30:27 UTC" level=info msg="capturing logs" argo=true
NAME:
   buildctl - build utility
USAGE:
   buildctl [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]
VERSION:
   v0.9.3
COMMANDS:
   du        disk usage
   prune     clean up build cache
   build, b  build
   debug     debug utilities
   help, h   Shows a list of commands or help for one command
GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --debug                enable debug output in logs
   --addr value           buildkitd address (default: "unix:///run/user/1000/buildkit/buildkitd.sock")
   --tlsservername value  buildkitd server name for certificate validation
   --tlscacert value      CA certificate for validation
   --tlscert value        client certificate
   --tlskey value         client key
   --tlsdir value         directory containing CA certificate, client certificate, and client key
   --timeout value        timeout backend connection after value seconds (default: 5)
   --help, -h             show help
   --version, -v          print the version
```

Any thoughts please what could be the problem